# Need to test an ajax timeout condition

Tags: asp.net, ajax, testing

As the title mentions, I have a timeout callback handler on an ajax call, and I want to be able to test that condition but nothing is coming to mind immediately on ways I can force my application to hit that state, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I think you need to be clearer in your question - what technology are you using and where is this process that is timing out - server-side or client-side?

If you want to have the server-side code take a long time and you are using .NET, place this line in the method you call server-side:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeoutMilliseconds);
```

As long as you use a number sufficient so that your client-side code assumes the server has timed out, you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

You could always run a server-side script that keeps running for a period of time. 
For example:

```
<?php
   sleep(10); //sleep for 10 seconds.
   print "This script has finished.";
>
```

Answer (score 1):

[YUI Connection Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/) allows you to introduce slowdown in your Javascript to test AJAX against latency.